# Connect with an already created named pipe with boost

Tags: c++, windows, boost, ipc

I'm looking in to using third party libraries for IPC communication using `named pipes` on `Windows`. I've been using the `Win32` `API` for this for the last few years. I was interested in replacing my implementation with a tried and true open source library.

I noticed that `boost::process` has an implementation of an `async_pipe` which would allow me to use it with `boost::asio` which would be really helpful for my application.

What I'm trying to do is create the `named pipe` on the server, which is a `C#` application. 
Once the `pipe` has been created, connect to it with a client using the `boost::process::async_pipe`.

The problem I'm having is I don't see an API in `boost::process` that would allow me to connect with an already created `named pipe`. The `constructors` for `async_pipe` create the `pipe` instead of connecting to an already created `pipe`.

Below is the code I'm currently using in the client which is erroneously creating the `pipe`

```
boost::asio::io_context ctx;
std::vector<char> buffer( 8196, 0 );

boost::process::async_pipe pipe{ ctx, R"(\\.\pipe\TestPipe)" }; 

boost::asio::async_read( pipe, boost::asio::buffer( buffer ),
    [ &buffer ]( const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t size )
    {
        if ( ec )
            std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message( ) << '\n';
        else
        {
            std::string message{ std::begin( buffer ), std::begin( buffer ) + size };
            std::cout << "Received message: " << message << '\n';
        }
    } );

ctx.run( );
```

I'm unsure if I can use `boost::process` to achieve what I want. I'm wondering if there is a way I could use `CreateFileW` to connect with the `named pipe` and then pass the `HANDLE` to `async_pipe` but I haven't found any documentation regarding that.

**Question**

How can I connect with an already created `named pipe` using `boost`

Comment: for connect to already created named pipe you need simply call `CreateFileW` . what is do `async_pipe`,how it goo at all for asynchronous i/o hard say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I was going about it the wrong way.
After reading this issue on Github [Link](https://github.com/boostorg/process/issues/83) I realized I needed to use a `stream_handle` instead. Note, the `pipe` must be opened in `OVERLAPPED` mode for this to work.

**Creating the `stream_handle`**

```
static boost::asio::windows::stream_handle OpenPipe( io_context& context )
{
    constexpr const wchar_t* pipeName{ LR"(\\.\pipe\TestPipe)" };
    return { context, CreateFileW( pipeName,
                                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                   0, nullptr,
                                   OPEN_EXISTING,
                                   FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                   nullptr ) };
}
```

Once the `stream_handle` is created you can use the `async` functions it provides for communication.

**Using the `stream_handle`**

```
std::vector<char> buffer( 8196, 0 );
pipe.async_read_some( boost::asio::buffer( buffer ), 
    [ &buffer ]( auto ec, auto size ) { } );
```

Comment: May I know what type is the `pipe`?  I can make it read successfully by `boost::asio::windows::stream_handle(OpenPipe(pipe_context)).async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), [&buffer](auto ec, auto size) {});` but I need to run step by step or it always fails...I need to seperate this code piece...

Comment: @VannesYang The `OpenPipe` function creates an `stream_handle` via `aggregate initialization`. If you want to create the pipe in `main` for example, do this: `stream_handle sh{ context, CreateFileW( pipeName, ... ) };`